# How to pass hidden value in a form?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<p>{{item.name}}</p>         // Please note that this works and shows fine
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" novalidate>
    <div *ngIf="editMode">
        <input name="name" type="hidden" ngModel value="{{item.name}}"> 
        <input name="eat1" type="text" ngModel > 
        <input name="eat2" type="text" ngModel >
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am able to pass `eat1` and `eat2` as expected, but don't see `name`.

Here's the output:

```
{name: "", eat1: "Bacon", eat2: "Egg"}
```

Should be:

```
{name: "Breakfast", eat1: "Bacon", eat2: "Egg"}
```

These didn't work:

```
 <input name="name" type="hidden" ngModel value="item.name"> 
 <input name="name" type="hidden" ngModel value={{item.name}}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the value to the `ngModel` attribute and it should work:

Had created a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-hidden-input-value) for your reference.

```
 <input name="name" type="hidden" [ngModel]="item.name">
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove value attribute and set `ngModel={{your_value}}` because you are using `ngModel` and value at a time:

HTML Code:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" novalidate>
    <div *ngIf="editMode">
        <input name="name" type="hidden" ngModel="{{item.name}}"> 
        <input name="eat1" type="text" ngModel> 
        <input name="eat2" type="text" ngModel>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyz7qn)

Answer (score 1):

try a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" value="some-thing" name="eat1" />
```

Hope this will work for

Answer (score 0):

javascript doesn't include elements that're hidden.

what you should to is to **serialize the form**, then append the *hidden element* to the resultant object.

*note that this is in javascript, apply this concept to Angular*

```
let obj = form.serializeArray(); // expected result: {name: "", eat1: "Bacon", eat2: "Egg"}

// update name key
obj['name'] = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]');
```